# Complex binding in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have the following property on my object

```
public Dictionary<string, Tuple<string, bool>> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
```

I would like the Value of the dictionary to bind to the checkbox's isChecked property.

`IsChecked="{Binding ((Tuple<string,bool>)Value).Item2}"` which gives me an error.Pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings use reflection to access properties and their values. You reference by property names only, or combined with numeric indexes (kind of like a path to the element name). You do not use C# casting.

I would need to know more about your model to get this right, but it will be more like:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=AnswerOptions[1].Value}"
```

But that will not work because of your data types.

Can you provide enough code to build a sample of your data object and more Xaml? Then I can provide something more useful to your specific example.